# CSS Nav bar Collapse down Menu issue

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, menu, navigation

I'm trying to customise the navigation bar on a website. The part that I'm having trouble with is the three line thing that should reveal the rest of the menu in a drop down way when the screen is small.

When I click on the 3 line button, nothing happens and I can't access the rest of the menu bar but it changes colour when I click it so I know it knows that I have clicked on it.

Here is my application.html file:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navbar-collapse">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
  <%= link_to 'Home', root_path, class: 'navbar-brand' %>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <%= render 'layouts/navigation_links' %>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

and here is the layout/navigation_links that list the links that I want to show

```
 <%# add navigation links to this file %>
 <% if user_signed_in? %>
   <li><%= link_to 'Edit account', edit_user_registration_path %></li>
   <li><%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, :method=>'delete' %></li>
 <% else %>
   <li><%= link_to 'Sign in', new_user_session_path %></li>
   <li><%= link_to 'Sign up', new_user_registration_path %></li>
 <% end %>
 <% if user_signed_in? %>
   <li><%= link_to 'Users', users_path %></li>
 <% end %>
```

and here is my application.css file (under assets/stylesheets)

```
 body{
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
 }
 .navbar-inverse{
    background-color: #000000;
 }
 .navbar-inverse{ 
    border-color: #33aa22;
 }
```

When the webpage is full size the rest of the menu bar appears and the navigation_links appear and work.
I have no clue why it isnt working when the page is small so any help would be great!

Comment: It sounds like you are missing the collapse.js part of bootstrap.  Are you including the bootstrap js as well as css?  Are they loading correctly?

Comment: @bwarren2 i think so, I have this near the top : <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: That is a stylesheet that will include the CSS you need, but you also need the JavaScript to match.  Include a script tag with a href of http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: Href should be src there, but I can't edit on my phone.